# Magento 2 Checkout: Get Custom field value in payment method

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

I have created custom form field, `payment['token_id']` in payment method . The problem is I can't get the `payment['token_id'] value`, i have tried $payment->getData('token_id') but nothing happen.

Here what i have tried:

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\SampleModule\Model;

use Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface;

class Payment extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Cc {

     const CODE = 'vendorname_samplemodule';

     protected $_code = self::CODE;
     protected $_infoBlockType = 'VendorName\SampleModule\Block\Info\Cc';

     //optional as per our requirmenet
     protected $_isGateway = true;
     protected $_canAuthorize = true;
     protected $_canCapture = true;
     protected $_canCapturePartial = false;
     protected $_canRefund = true;
     protected $_canVoid = true;
     protected $_canUseInternal = true;
     protected $_canUseCheckout = true;
     protected $_canUseForMultishipping = true;
     protected $_authorize = '';
     protected $_authorizeError = false;
     protected $_debugReplacePrivateDataKeys = ['card', 'merc'];    

     public function authorize(InfoInterface $payment, $amount) {                

         $order      = $payment->getOrder();        
         $billing    = $order->getBillingAddress();
         $shipping   = $order->getShippingAddress();


         foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){
             $proId[]    = $item->getProductId();        
             $proName[]  = $item->getName(); 
             $proPrice[] = $item->getPrice();
             $proQty[]   = $item->getQtyToInvoice();
             $proSku[]   = $item->getSku();
         }

         // TESTING
         $data  = '';
         $data .= 'Order ID :'. $order->getIncrementId();
         $data .= PHP_EOL;
         $data .= 'Email :'.$order->getCustomerEmail();
         $data .= PHP_EOL;        
         $data .= 'Cc :'.$payment->getCcNumber();
         $data .= PHP_EOL;        
         $data .= 'Exp Month :'.sprintf('%02d',$payment->getCcExpMonth());
         $data .= PHP_EOL;        
         $data .= 'Exp Year :'.$payment->getCcExpYear();
         $data .= PHP_EOL;        
         $data .= 'CCV :'.$payment->getCcCid();
         $data .= PHP_EOL;        
         $data .= 'Amount: '.$amount;
         $data .= PHP_EOL;
         $data .= 'Customer Postcode :'.$shipping->getPostcode();
         $data .= PHP_EOL;
         $data .= 'Customer Region :'.$shipping->getRegion();
         $data .= PHP_EOL;
         $data .= 'Customer Country ID :'.$shipping->getCountryId();
         $data .= PHP_EOL;        
         $data .= 'Is Customer Is Guest ?'.$order->getCustomerIsGuest();
         $data .= PHP_EOL;        
         $data .= 'Customer ID : '.$order->getCustomerId();    
         $data .= PHP_EOL;

            /** RETURN : EMPTY **/
         $data .= 'Token ID : '.$payment->getData('token_id');


         file_put_contents('/home/zulkhaery/www/tes/test.txt',$data);
         return $this;
     }   
}
```

Any idea how to get the value of `payment['token_id']` ?